# addAnimation to UINavigationController cause UINavigationController's view (layer) displayed on the topmost layer

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation

I am trying to add a cool animation effect to the UINavigationController, however I found once I do it it will mess up the other views displayed on top of other views which suppose to be on  top of it.

e.g.  navivc is a UINavigationController 
      overlayview is a subview of navivc's superview, and placed on top of navivc.

```
  ...
  CATransform3D t1 = CATransform3DIdentity;
  t1.m34 = 1.0/-900;
  t1 = CATransform3DScale(t1, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3);
  t1 = CATransform3DRotate(t1, 15.0f*M_PI/180.0f, 1, 0, 0);

  CABasicAnimation *move = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform" ];
  //[move setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
  [move setToValue:[NSNumber valueWithCATransform3D:t1]];
  [move setDuration:0.3f];
  move.removedOnCompletion = NO;
  move.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
  [move setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
  CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
  group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
  group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
  [group setDuration:0.3f];
  [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:move, nil]];

  [navivc.view.layer addAnimation:move forKey:@"coolanimation"];

  ...
```

The animation is normal and correct, however now navivc's view show on top of overlayview.

Seemed the problem only happen on "transform" path, I tried other key paths, e.g. position, scale, translation etc., all those seemed to be correct. But the 3D transform messed up the view on top.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against animating a view controller's content view. Instead, create a container view inside the view controller's content view and animate that.

It isn't clear from your post where overlayView is in your view hierarchy, so it's hard to give you specific instructions on how to prevent your animation from covering your overlay view. You might try changing the zPosition of the overlayView's layer to make it appear above the layer you are animating.